# Inspircd + Comodo InstantSSL - can it be done?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, irc, inspircd

I have a new Inspircd server setup for some gaming clans and I want to use a Comodo InstantSSL cert for the GnuTLS connections.

I noticed that in the config files you can point to the certs so it should work but what I am confused about is what I tell Comodo for the type of server when doing the setup? with Zimbra I used Tomcat, for my Apache setup I used Apache but what about Inspircd?

I looked for information/guides but did not find much on the subject.

I am running Inspircd 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

That "type of server" question just determines how the certificate file you download is formatted. Different software (servers, etc) expects different formats for the certificate file. Unfortunately InspIRCd's documentation is not clear on what format it expects, but I believe it should be the same as Apache. If it doesn't work, you can always go back to Comodo and re-download the certificate in a different format -- there is a fairly straightforward way to do this.